# How to add new elements to the page via function calls, and attach event handlers to them, without specifying them inside the function?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

So I have an app. It's written on jQuery(UI & Mobile).

I have this page structure:

**Main Page**:

```
    <!-- Main Page -->
    <div data-role="page" id="home">
        <header data-role="header" data-theme="a">
            <h1>Running Tracker</h1>
        </header>
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#add" data-transition="fade" data-icon="plus">Add Run</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <h3>Welcome to the RunningTracker App</h3>
            <p>
                With this app you can track your running, jogging or walking.
            </p>

            <h3>Your Latest Runs:</h3>

            <ul id="stats" class="current"  data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Filter runs by date or distance." data-inset="true" ></ul>
            <br/>
            <button id="clearRuns" onclick="return confirm('Are You Sure?')">
                Clear Data
            </button>
        </div>
        <footer data-role="footer">
            <h4>RunningTracker &copy; 2015 GZ</h4>
        </footer>
    </div>
```

**Add New Entry Page**:

```
        <!-- Add Run Page -->
        <div data-role="page" id="add">
            <header data-role="header" data-theme="a">
                <h1>Running Tracker</h1>
            </header>
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#home" data-transition="fade" data-icon="home">Home</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <h3>Add Run</h3>
                <form id="addForm">
                    <label for="km">Enter Kilometres:</label>
                    <input type="number" id="addKms" required>
                    <label for="km">Enter Date:</label>
                    <input type="date" data-role="date" class="date" id="addDate" data-inline="true" required>
                    <button id="submitAdd" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all">
                        Add Run
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <footer data-role="footer">
                <h4>RunningTracker &copy; 2015 GZ</h4>
            </footer>
        </div>
```

And I have a function to add new Runs, so when you are adding a new entry, application replaces current `home` page with `edit` page by using `data-transition` method.

On that page I enter all the needed data to the form and submit it using this function:

`addRun`:

```
function addRun() {
            /*
             * Data Manipulation Here
             */

            //Redirect back to Home page after form is submitted
            $("body").pagecontainer("change", "#home", {
                transition : "fade",
                reverse : true
            });

            //Here I hide all Original Entries that are currently displayed(they have class "original"
            $('.original').hide();
            //Here I display all the entries again, including the new ones
            showRuns();
            //Here I add EventHandlers again, to newly created Elements
        }
    }
```

So as you can see I have to replicate same actions in every function I execute if I want to keep all the needed handlers on elements.

So in a nutshell why I am doing it like this:

1) I load my current view like this:

```
    $(document).on("pagecreate", "#home", function() {
        //Showing All Current Entries
        showRuns();
        //Attaching Event Handlers
        $('#submitAdd').on('tap', addRun);
        $('#submitEdit').on('tap', editRun);
        $('.editLink').on('tap', setCurrent);
        $('.deleteLink').on('tap', function() {
            var confirmation = confirm("Are you sure?");
            if (confirmation) {
                setCurrent.call(this);
                deleteRun.call(this);
            }
        });
        $('#clearRuns').on('tap', clearAll);

        //Declaring all functions that I use in eventHandlers below

});
```

2) Then I switch to `#add` page to add new entry.

3) I add add new entry and get switched back to the main page. If I do so without calling `showRuns` function inside my `addRuns` function, I won't see the new entry I've just added, I will have to reload the page to see it.

4) If I will call `showRuns` function inside my `addRuns` function I will see duplicated entries, because function will be called again on each `addRun` call.

5) To see new entry after I add it I have to remove all other entries from main page, that have class `current` and after that I call `showRuns` function that will add all entries to the main page again, **BUT** they won't have any event handlers because they were created after page was loaded.

6) So now I have to add all the handlers again.

I have a feeling there must be a better way to do what I want - to add new elements to the page, without the need to do all the steps I've described above.

I've tried reloading the [page-container](https://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#method-change) by using it like this:

```
$("body").pagecontainer("change", "#home", {
                transition : "fade",
                reload : true
            });
```

But If I do so, it has no effect.

Here is live Demo: http://runningtracker.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using event delegation: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

This lets you put the event on the container and then delegate it to elements within the container whether they exist at design time or not.

Change

```
    $('.editLink').on('tap', setCurrent);
    $('.deleteLink').on('tap', function() {...
```

To

```
    $(document).on('tap','.editLink', setCurrent);
    $(document).on('tap','.deleteLink', function() {...
```